# Problem with Android Silent Notifications that doesn't require user interaction (using GX16 U7 Android SD Generator )

Tags: genexus, genexus-sd

On Android devices (with OS version 6,7,8 or 9) when being inside any application panel, splash screen is always shown when a silent notification arrives. This behaviour cause a nuisance and some confusion to users.

[Video Showing this behavior](https://mail.inalambrik.com.ec/d/inalambrik.com.ec/zrfpzQ/beY)

Until GX16 U6 this was not happening.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the report.
This issue is already reported here :
https://www2.genexusnet.com/gxpintranet/hgxpp001.aspx?1,14,96,O,S,0,MNU;E;34;1;MNU;,46930
and it will be solved in the beta channel soon and include in the next release.

Sorry for the inconvenient.